# Realtime notifications using socket.io or any other better option ? Want instant notifications like whatsapp

Tags: android, push-notification, socket.io, notifications

I am working on a travel app, notifications play a very vital role, as the app involves payments and instant verification. Please suggest how it can be achieved.

Will keeping a service for socket.io connection drain a lot of battery?

will the device kill the service when the user swipe kills the app from recent apps?

Comment: Check out Pushy (https://pushy.me/) which aims to improve notification reliability and speed in comparison to Firebase Cloud Messaging, using a custom implementation of the MQTT protocol. Full disclosure - I founded Pushy.

Answer (score 1):

The socket.io connection does seem to drain a fair amount of battery in my experience. I open and close the socket connection depending on if the app is in the foreground. Otherwise, I use [Firedbase Cloud Messaing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to deliver the notifications. This is kind of annoying since you're delivering the Notifications twice, but if you want quick notifications and don't want to drain the phone's battery, there's not a great solution. The only other way would involve tracking the message read state on from the socket.io client and them firing off a FCM notification from there.

Comment: how whatsapp doing it so fast?

Comment: They use FCM just like everyone else

Comment: @MattW Actually they don't. They use their own XMPP connection implementation.

Comment: Is that true even in the instances of iOS? Because you either have to use APNS or trigger the notification locally.